# Android studio if empty field

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a register page and i implemented code to check if the username is empty and if it is to give an error statement but it isn't working . No error message just not doing it's job . I can click the register button and if there is no info in it it still goes into the database . This is the code that isn't working .

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
} else {
}
```

RegisterActivity :

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
            } else {

            }

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new   Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("User details already in use")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest( username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Try `if (username.equals(""))` and you really should put the code to you want to run, if there is text found, inside your `else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Log is not equal to exception. It will **NOT** terminate your method. Log is just recording message. In this case, you log down the problem if `username` is empty but you do not specify what to do, so the program goes on.

There are two ways you can solve it.

**Method 1**

There are nothing you want to do after checking `username` is empty. Then,

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
    Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
    return;
}
```

**Method 2**

There are something you want to process after checking `username` is empty. Then,

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
    Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
} else {
    // Do something if username is not empty
}
// Do something no matter if username is empty or not
```

Comment: I am trying to put the last curly bracket after the registration is successful for my else statement

Comment: You should probably put the bracket like this `else { ....  queue.add(registerRequest);}`.

Answer (score 0):

The else part of your program should extend more than just a blank line. Extend the else block till the end of operation.

Comment: or even better just add a `return;` right after the Log statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if (etUsername.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
        } else {


     Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage("User details already in use")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest( username, password, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
    queue.add(registerRequest);  


        }
```

The rest of your code should go in your else block.

Comment: When I put in this code and click my register button it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
        } else {

        }

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        Intent intent = new   Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("User details already in use")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest( username, password, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);
```

Correct:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) 
{
            Log.d(TAG, "Username is empty. Please fill it in .");
} 
else 
{
       Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        Intent intent = new   Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("User details already in use")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest( username, password, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);   
}
```

Comment: When I put in this code and click my register button it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use your EditText to check if empty

```
public boolean checkIfEmpty(EditText edt) {
    String str = edt.getText().toString().trim();
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(str) || str.length() == 0;
}
```

Here's how to check

```
if (checkIfEmpty(editText)){
    editText.setError("Your error message");
    return;
}
```

Comment: import android.text.TextUtils;

Comment: I'm getting error on five differents parts of  if (checkIfEmpty(editText)){
    editText.setError("Your error message");
    return;
}

Comment: Im very sory. romove static from function like that